# "When will you come" vs. "When are you coming"?

Tags: grammaticality, british-english

One of my friends will come to my city "Ahmedabad" on 18th May 2015.

In a WhatsApp group chat, my friend asked him,

> "When are you coming to Ahmedabad?"

I corrected my friend:

> "When will you come to Ahmedabad?"

Which one is the correct sentence and why? If it is wrong then also correct me with reason.

Comment: This is an elementary question. It would be better on the English language Learners site.

Comment: Hi @Hemang, There are actually two sites in the StackExchange network that deal exclusively with questions regarding English, and your question is likely to get better results on the other site: http://ell.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are correct in meaning, although different in structure the definition remains the same, but to clarify in no.2 the present continuous as well as being used to talk about the things taking place at the current moment can also be used to refer to future events that might be happening shortly or at some point in the future.

Examples:

- "Are you going to come to work tommorow?"-"No, I'm not going" or alternatively: "I'won't be coming", "I'm not going to be coming", "I'm not coming" though the last one is rather informal, I find it is quite often used in casual speech.

Answer (score 2):

Present Continuous is also used for arrangements, meetings, something on your schedule. Future Simple is a plan you say in a moment of speaking and it isn't something fixed, just a general future time. You can say *I will go to the Mars* but it's something you just decided on the spur of the moment. Both sentences are correct, except second example is more general.